# Cheapest solution to monitor gigabit internet connection performance

Tags: performance, linux-networking, network-speed

I want to perform `speedtest-cli` performance tests of the internet connection of a fibre connection which is advertised to 1Gbps at regular intervals, say every hour, for one year. I have been looking at single board computers such as banana-pi which has advertised 10/100/1000 ethernet. But [performance tests](https://www.htpcguides.com/raspberry-vs-banana-pi-benchmarks-sata-gigabit-matter/) show that it still doesnt have 1Gbits throughput even though it is advertised as having gigabit ethernet. People with the same aim as me, may have the following questions:

- What could be limiting the performance in single board computers such as banana-pi?
- What is the cheapest fanless computer which could perform such tests reliably? What is the relevant hardware specificantions required?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use public speed test sites like Ookla's Speedtest for testing 1 Gbps connections. Take a look at [Speedtest Server Requirements](https://support.ookla.com/hc/en-us/articles/234578628-Speedtest-Server-Requirements) and picture situation where the opposite side has...

> **Network Capacity**
>
> - **1 Gbps** Upstream and Downstream Capacity
> - Rare exceptions are made for underdeveloped and underserved regions.

For your test to be reliable

- you would need to be the only one performing the test at the present time.
- the connection needs to be reserved for the testing alone. (I wouldn't pay such line for testing.)
- every router between the final destinations would need to be able to do the same.

Instead, you could e.g.

1. Have a dedicated remote server for this testing, having the same bandwidth at minimum.
2. Generate traffic between these two connections.
3. Measure the total throughput at your switch or router.

Personally, I'd be more interested in whether the connection is enough for its real utilization.